# The maximality of a family of pairwise disjoint meager open sets implies the denseness of its union

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following theorem from A. Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*:

> **(8.29) Theorem.** Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Put $$U(A) = \bigcup \{ U\text{ open} : U \Vdash A \}.$$ Then $U(A) \setminus A$ is meager, and if $A$ has the [Baire Property], $A \setminus U(A)$, and thus $A \mathop{\Delta} U(A)$, is meager, so $A =^* U(A)$.

(Here $U \Vdash A$ means that $A$ is *comeager* in $U$, or $U \setminus A$ is meager.)

In following the proof for the case $A = \varnothing$, we begin with the family $$\mathscr U=\{\mathcal U: \mathcal U\text{ is a pairwise disjoint subfamily of meager open subsets of }X \}.$$ Then let $ \{U_i \}_{i\in I} $ be a maximal element of $\mathscr U$. (Such a family $ \{U_i \}_{i\in I} $ can be chosen by Zorn's Lemma.) Letting $W=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$, the maximality of $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ implies that $W$ is dense in $U(\varnothing)$.

My question is, why does the maximality of $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ imply the denseness of the set $W$ in $U(\varnothing)$?

Comment: @bof: my question is from      math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279689/intersection-about-the-second-category. andwhere I ask Alex Ravsky.I slightly changed the question of law

Comment: @bof: This question just used in a proof.

Comment: @DavidChan A comment of yours above links to a question where Alex Ravsky quotes Theorem 8.29 in Kechris, and your edit references Proposition 8.26. Of these, it appears that 8.29 is closer to what your question is about (though I fear that things have become confused somewhere since "$U \Vdash A$" means that $A$ is comeagre in $U$, or, $U \setminus A$ is meagre. To match, you have to take $A = \varnothing$, and we're talking about being dense in $U(\varnothing) = \varnothing$.)

Comment: @Arthur Fischer:$U(\varnothing)\neq \varnothing$

Comment: @DavidChan: Sorry, you're right. If $X$ fails to be a Baire space, then $U( \varnothing )$ is nonempty. (Still, the proof in Kechris talks about $W$ being dense in $U ( A )$, not necessarily in the entire underlying space.)

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Yes, I just want to know that why $W$ is dense in $U(A)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W$ is not dense in $U(\varnothing)$, then $U(\varnothing) \not\subseteq \overline{W}$, and so $U(\varnothing) \setminus \overline{W}$ is a nonempty open set. Picking any $x \in U(\varnothing) \setminus \overline{W}$ by definition of $U(\varnothing)$ there must be an open meager $U$ containing $x$. In particular, $U \cap (U(\varnothing) \setminus \overline{W})$ is a nonempty open set. Now *this* set is meager because it is a subset of the meager $U$, and is disjoint from each $U_i$, contradicting the maximality of $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$.